# How to use VueJS in mkdocs?

Tags: vue.js, mkdocs

is it possible to use VueJs in mkdocs? And if yes, how can I do it? I tried implementing it like this, but it doesn´t work. When I use the code in a normal HTML file it works properly. Is there anything I have to add so it will work properly?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
# Welcome to MkDocs
<h1 id="h1">Hallo</h1>
<div id="div1">
    <button id="btn1" v-on:click="readData">Klick hier</button>
    <ul id="ul1"v-for="item in test">
        <li>Name: {{item.name}}, Nummer: {{item.number}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>{{test1}}</p>
</div>
script">Vue.createApp({
    data:function(){
    return{
        test: null,
        test1: "Guten Tag"
    }
},
methods: {
    readData: function(){
            fetch("./test.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {console.log(data);
        this.test = data;
    })
        }
}
}).mount(#div1)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference by Vue.js offical documentation
I use section [Using Vue from CDN](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn)

Modification for your example code

```html
# Welcome to MkDocs

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <!-- Your Code -->
  <button id="btn1" v-on:click="readData">Klick hier</button>
  <ul id="ul1" v-for="item in test">
    <li>Name: {{item.name}}, Nummer: {{item.number}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>{{test1}}</p>  
</div>

<script>
  const { createApp, ref } = Vue

  createApp({
    setup() {
      const message = ref('Hello vue!')
      const test = ref([
        {
          name: 'test',
          number: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Test',
          number: 2
        }
      ])
      const test1 = ref('test1')
      const readData = function() {
        console.log("readData")
        fetch('./test.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.test = data
          })
      }

      return {
        message,
        test,
        test1,
        readData
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Result:

[image]